# Extracting data from a nested div block using Beautiful Soup 4

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and web scraping and need some help. I am trying to scrap a section of a web page which is a nested  block. I want to export all these blocks to a csv. I have written the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
patent = "US20170293299"
urla = "https://patents.google.com/patent/"+patent
list1 = []

page = urllib2.urlopen(urla)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
list1 = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'claim-text')

for x in range(len(list1)):
    print list1[x]
    print '\n'
```

This is the output that I am getting after running the code in Pycharm

```
<div class="claim-text"> <b>1</b>. An automated driving system of a vehicle comprising: <div class="claim-text">a surrounding environment information acquiring device acquiring surrounding environment information relating to surrounding environment conditions of the vehicle;</div> <div class="claim-text">a vehicle information acquiring device acquiring vehicle information relating to conditions of the vehicle;</div> <div class="claim-text">a driver information acquiring device acquiring driver information relating to conditions of a driver of the vehicle;</div> <div class="claim-text">an automated driving executing part executing automated driving of the vehicle based on a driving assistance package packaging permissions for a plurality of driving assistance operations;</div> <div class="claim-text">a package determining part determining a driving assistance package to be proposed to the driver based on at least one of the surrounding environment information, the vehicle information, and the driver information,</div> <div class="claim-text">a package proposing part proposing the driving assistance package determined by the package determining part to the driver; and</div> <div class="claim-text">an emergency condition judging part judging if the driver is in an emergency condition based on the driver information, wherein</div> <div class="claim-text">the automated driving executing part performs automated driving of the vehicle based on an emergency driving assistance package packaging permissions of the plurality of driving assistance operations when the driver is in an emergency condition, if the emergency condition judging part judges that the driver is in an emergency condition, and performs automated driving of the vehicle based on the driving assistance package proposed by the packaging proposing part and approved by the driver, if the emergency condition judging part judges that the driver is not in an emergency condition.</div> </div>


<div class="claim-text">a surrounding environment information acquiring device acquiring surrounding environment information relating to surrounding environment conditions of the vehicle;</div>


<div class="claim-text">a vehicle information acquiring device acquiring vehicle information relating to conditions of the vehicle;</div>


<div class="claim-text">a driver information acquiring device acquiring driver information relating to conditions of a driver of the vehicle;</div>


<div class="claim-text">an automated driving executing part executing automated driving of the vehicle based on a driving assistance package packaging permissions for a plurality of driving assistance operations;</div>


<div class="claim-text">a package determining part determining a driving assistance package to be proposed to the driver based on at least one of the surrounding environment information, the vehicle information, and the driver information,</div>


<div class="claim-text">a package proposing part proposing the driving assistance package determined by the package determining part to the driver; and</div>


<div class="claim-text">an emergency condition judging part judging if the driver is in an emergency condition based on the driver information, wherein</div>


<div class="claim-text">the automated driving executing part performs automated driving of the vehicle based on an emergency driving assistance package packaging permissions of the plurality of driving assistance operations when the driver is in an emergency condition, if the emergency condition judging part judges that the driver is in an emergency condition, and performs automated driving of the vehicle based on the driving assistance package proposed by the packaging proposing part and approved by the driver, if the emergency condition judging part judges that the driver is not in an emergency condition.</div>


<div class="claim-text"> <b>2</b>. The vehicle automated driving system according to <claim-ref idref="CLM-00001">claim 1</claim-ref>, wherein <div class="claim-text">the package determining part determines a driving assistance package to be proposed to the driver based on the driver information, and</div> <div class="claim-text">the emergency condition judging part judges that the driver is in an emergency condition when the driving assistance package determined by the package determining part is the emergency driving assistance package.</div> </div>


<div class="claim-text">the package determining part determines a driving assistance package to be proposed to the driver based on the driver information, and</div>


<div class="claim-text">the emergency condition judging part judges that the driver is in an emergency condition when the driving assistance package determined by the package determining part is the emergency driving assistance package.</div>


<div class="claim-text"> <b>3</b>. The vehicle automated driving system according to <claim-ref idref="CLM-00001">claim 1</claim-ref>, wherein <div class="claim-text">the system further comprises an alarm part issuing a warning to the driver, and</div> <div class="claim-text">the automated driving executing part performs automated driving of the vehicle based on the emergency driving assistance package if the emergency condition judging part judges that the driver is in an emergency condition after the warning by the alarm part.</div> </div>


<div class="claim-text">the system further comprises an alarm part issuing a warning to the driver, and</div>


<div class="claim-text">the automated driving executing part performs automated driving of the vehicle based on the emergency driving assistance package if the emergency condition judging part judges that the driver is in an emergency condition after the warning by the alarm part.</div>


<div class="claim-text"> <b>4</b>. The vehicle automated driving system according to <claim-ref idref="CLM-00002">claim 2</claim-ref>, wherein <div class="claim-text">the system further comprises an alarm part issuing a warning to the driver, and</div> <div class="claim-text">the automated driving executing part performs automated driving of the vehicle based on the emergency driving assistance package if the emergency condition judging part judges that the driver is in an emergency condition after the warning by the alarm part.</div> </div>


<div class="claim-text">the system further comprises an alarm part issuing a warning to the driver, and</div>


<div class="claim-text">the automated driving executing part performs automated driving of the vehicle based on the emergency driving assistance package if the emergency condition judging part judges that the driver is in an emergency condition after the warning by the alarm part.</div>


<div class="claim-text"> <b>5</b>. The vehicle automated driving system according to <claim-ref idref="CLM-00003">claim 3</claim-ref>, wherein the alarm part issues the warning to the driver by sound.</div>


<div class="claim-text"> <b>6</b>. The vehicle automated driving system according to <claim-ref idref="CLM-00004">claim 4</claim-ref>, wherein the alarm part issues the warning to the driver by sound.</div>


<div class="claim-text"> <b>7</b>. The vehicle automated driving system according to <claim-ref idref="CLM-00003">claim 3</claim-ref>, wherein the alarm part issues the warning to the driver by changing the behavior of the vehicle.</div>


<div class="claim-text"> <b>8</b>. The vehicle automated driving system according to <claim-ref idref="CLM-00004">claim 4</claim-ref>, wherein the alarm part issues the warning to the driver by changing the behavior of the vehicle.</div>


<div class="claim-text"> <b>9</b>. The vehicle automated driving system according to <claim-ref idref="CLM-00005">claim 5</claim-ref>, wherein the alarm part issues the warning to the driver by changing the behavior of the vehicle.</div>


<div class="claim-text"> <b>10</b>. The vehicle automated driving system according to <claim-ref idref="CLM-00006">claim 6</claim-ref>, wherein the alarm part issues the warning to the driver by changing the behavior of the vehicle.</div>


<div class="claim-text"> <b>11</b>. The vehicle automated driving system according to <claim-ref idref="CLM-00001">claim 1</claim-ref>, wherein in the emergency driving assistance package, an auto stop control of the vehicle and a hazard light turn on control of the vehicle are permitted.</div>


<div class="claim-text"> <b>12</b>. The vehicle automated driving system according to <claim-ref idref="CLM-00002">claim 2</claim-ref>, wherein in the emergency driving assistance package, an auto stop control of the vehicle and a hazard light turn on control of the vehicle are permitted.</div>


<div class="claim-text"> <b>13</b>. The vehicle automated driving system according to <claim-ref idref="CLM-00003">claim 3</claim-ref>, wherein in the emergency driving assistance package, an auto stop control of the vehicle and a hazard light turn on control of the vehicle are permitted.</div>


<div class="claim-text"> <b>14</b>. The vehicle automated driving system according to <claim-ref idref="CLM-00004">claim 4</claim-ref>, wherein in the emergency driving assistance package, an auto stop control of the vehicle and a hazard light turn on control of the vehicle are permitted.</div>


<div class="claim-text"> <b>15</b>. The vehicle automated driving system according to <claim-ref idref="CLM-00005">claim 5</claim-ref>, wherein in the emergency driving assistance package, an auto stop control of the vehicle and a hazard light turn on control of the vehicle are permitted.</div>


<div class="claim-text"> <b>16</b>. The vehicle automated driving system according to <claim-ref idref="CLM-00006">claim 6</claim-ref>, wherein in the emergency driving assistance package, an auto stop control of the vehicle and a hazard light turn on control of the vehicle are permitted.</div>


<div class="claim-text"> <b>17</b>. The vehicle automated driving system according to <claim-ref idref="CLM-00007">claim 7</claim-ref>, wherein in the emergency driving assistance package, an auto stop control of the vehicle and a hazard light turn on control of the vehicle are permitted.</div>


<div class="claim-text"> <b>18</b>. The vehicle automated driving system according to <claim-ref idref="CLM-00008">claim 8</claim-ref>, wherein in the emergency driving assistance package, an auto stop control of the vehicle and a hazard light turn on control of the vehicle are permitted.</div>


<div class="claim-text"> <b>19</b>. The vehicle automated driving system according to <claim-ref idref="CLM-00009">claim 9</claim-ref>, wherein in the emergency driving assistance package, an auto stop control of the vehicle and a hazard light turn on control of the vehicle are permitted.</div>


<div class="claim-text"> <b>20</b>. The vehicle automated driving system according to <claim-ref idref="CLM-00010">claim 10</claim-ref>, wherein in the emergency driving assistance package, an auto stop control of the vehicle and a hazard light turn on control of the vehicle are permitted.</div>



Process finished with exit code 0
```

The problem is, that whenever a group of text starts, the whole block is being read as one element, and the blocks that are nested inside that big block are being read separately. I do not want the whole block to be read as one big element.

```
<div class="claim-text">
      <b>
       1
      </b>
      . An automated driving system of a vehicle comprising:
      <div class="claim-text">
       a surrounding environment information acquiring device acquiring surrounding environment information relating to surrounding environment conditions of the vehicle;
      </div>
```

Look at the above HTML. I want the first row to contain 
"1. An automated driving system of a vehicle comprising:"
second row to contain 
"a surrounding environment information acquiring device acquiring surrounding environment information relating to surrounding environment conditions of the vehicle;" 
...and so on.

But the issue is, the data after the first row does not contain a  tag. So the entire first paragraph appears in the first list element. 
 
Here is the gist what I want to do: 
I want to extract all the text which **starts with** a `<div class = "claim-text">` tag and **ends with** either a `</div>` tag or a new `<div class = "claim-text">` tag.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the text and nothing else, simply use text attribute

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
patent = "US20170293299"
urla = "https://patents.google.com/patent/"+patent
list1 = []

page = urllib2.urlopen(urla)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
list1 = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'claim-text')

for x in range(len(list1)):
    print list1[x].text
    print '\n'
```

or you can access the inner div by finding again from your search result

```
print list1[x].find_all('div', class_ = 'claim-text')
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. The solution you offered only helps me to get the text out of the data, but not the actual data I want. For example, the first element of the list should ideally contain ONLY "1. An automated driving system of a vehicle comprising:" but instead the first element contains all the elements that follow (because of no </div> tag after the word 'comprising:').